# pass variable with Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have these code right now:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();<br/>
$uid = $signed_request['app_data'];
```

And I'm using Facebook PHP SDK  but I dont seem to be able to make it to work my link is

https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx?sk=app_1234567&app_data=uid%3Daaaaaaa

I'm trying to pass the variable `uid=aaaaaaaaa`

but is not working. can anyone help???

I need these because I have a like button with different id for each user picture but I need to pass these variable so when they come back to my page from the like link I need to know what is the user id.

Comment: Is this a page tab or a canvas app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed, i had to pages, the index.php detected if the user liked the page, so in the send page the variable didnt pass, thats the reason why it didnt work